# There is a library for String normalization in Java?

Tags: java, string, normalization, text-processing, punctuation

Yes, I know that there is a similar question, but I want a different thing.

I want to normalize punctuations, spaces, quotes, hyphens, etc., but not touch in the letters.

There a lot of different chars for double-quotes, single quotes, spaces, etc. I want to replace all possibilities with the default char.

At the moment, I'm using regex, but I'm gathering all possibilities I found and adding to regex manually. I want to know if there is a lib that can do this, but don't change the letters like replacing accented letter to a non-accented.

**EDIT:**

Here are some examples:

```
text.replaceAll("[–––—]", "-");
text.replaceAll("[\\u0000-\\u0009\\u000B-\\u001F\\u0080-\\u009F]", "");
replacedText = text.replaceAll("[“”“”““”“”“”“”“”]", "\"");
text.replaceAll("[\\u00A0\\u2000-\\u200B\\u205F\t]+", " ");
```

Much chars have the same font representation, but are different chars in Unicode.

Comment: What you are doing sounds pretty reasonable and any library will pretty much do the same, although I never heard of one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for the same reasons we do (full-text search/indexing), you could look at the text normalization features [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) provides. A good example is [here](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/11/14/full-text-search-with-mongodb-and-lucene-analyzers/).

Otherwise regex with Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes is your best bet.

Comment: I need only replacement of the punctuations. I looked at Lucene, but found nothing that can do this.